Why do I get two different expression for $dV$ by different methods?
So, I was taught that if we have to find the component for a very small change in volume say $dV$ then it is equal to the product of total surface of the object say $s$ and the small thickness say $dr$.
For example let us take a sphere of radius $r$, then by this method,
$$dV = 4πr^2dr.$$
Now, if we use calculus, then,
$$V = \frac{4}{3}πr^3$$
$$dV = 4πr^2dr$$
Now both the expressions are equal and this the same case for a cylinder as well, but for a cube of side length say $r$ the expression by the method comes out to be,
$$dV = 6r^2dr.$$
Now by the calculus method,
$$ V = r^3$$
$$ dV = 3r^2dr.$$
Now, we have two different expressions for $dV$ however this should not be possible in maths as both the expressions are not equal to each other.
Am I doing something wrong here or am I missing something? And if I ever have to take the component in physics should I always go with the earlier method and not the calculus approach?

think about what happens to opposite faces and the total change in side length

There's an interesting observation that if you scale what your length parameter is, the area and volume scale differently, so you can tune r so that the formula works, it turns out to work for spheres with the standard radius. This reminds me of this video I saw https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=0vYWsOBBXxw where for regular polygons, the "right length parameter" turns out to be the radius of the inscribed circle. The same works here if instead of considering the side of the cube, r, you consider the radius of the inscribed sphere so that the side is 2r.

To make it easier imagine doing this for a cuboid instead, where we're just growing one of the three side lengths not all three.
Imagine we have a cuboid with side lengths $(a,b,c)$ and we grow $a\mapsto a+da$. This gives you an infinitesimal slab of side lengths $b$ and $c$ but we get one of these slabs at each end of the side we grew and each one of these two has thickness $da/2$.
Going back to the original case of imagining growing a cube from side length $r$ to $r+dr$ we get 6 infinitesimal slabs but each is only of thickness $dr/2$.
Alternatively doing the calculus properly avoids this mistake.

I understand. So the above expression derived through product method actually assumes that we increase the side by $2dr$ and I should go by calculus in general as it is correct in general.

You are trying to differentiate from first principles and failing with the cube.
Multiply this expression out and take the limit.
$\delta V = (r+\delta r)^3 -r^3 \to 3\, r^2 \,\delta r$ to the first order in $\delta r$ as $\delta r \to 0$.
You can do a similar thing for the sphere with one variable, the radius.
Note that for the cylinder there are two independent variables, the length and the radius, and I think that you happened to vary the length.
Following on from the cylinder, the cube has the three independent variables of a cuboid amalgamated into one variable, the length of each of the sides, as is the case for a sphere which is a particular example of an ellipsoid.
